# using call_user_func_array() in codeigniter's _remap method

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url, remap

[`call_user_func_array()`'s PHP manual's examples](http://ir.php.net/call_user_func_array) can only make me more confused with those `foo` and `bar` variables!

Anyway, please consider the `_remap` and `ComplexFunction` below:

```
class MyClass extends CI_Controller
{

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }

    }

    public function ComplexFunction($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4)
    {
        // process
        return 'done';
    }

}
```

Now will this piece of code work correctly?

```
$params = array(
                'param1' => '1',
                'param2' => '2',
                'param3' => '3',
                'param4' => '4'
               );

$myObject = new MyClass();

$output = call_user_func_array(array($myObject, 'ComplexFunction'), $params);

echo $output;
```

1. Will the `$output` be `done`?
2. Is that a reliable method to use in codeigniter's `_remap()` function?

Comment: Did you tried it? Why are you instantiating the controller like that?

Comment: In fact I was looking for a general way. This is not the way that I use my controller. There are also many other methods in my controller. I should use the `_remap` function because the `search()` method should has many optional parameters that are passed in user defined order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work, as the `_remap()` function is called by CI's core functions, and it's passed a separate argument for each segment in the matched route.  You should never have to call the `_remap()` method yourself!